# Print report if condition in Qweb Odoo 8

Tags: odoo-8, qweb

I'm working with Qweb and Odoo 8, I've created my report in RH module, the problem is how can i print this report if condition

in `hr_contract` I've added a one2many fields

```
_columns = {
    'contract_job_ids': fields.one2many(
        'hr.contract.job',
        'contract_id',
        'Jobs',
    ),
```

I want print this report just if the `len(object.contract_job_ids) >= 2`

Comment: Did you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run specific code before your report prints (or not) you can create an Abstract model which defines a render_html function so that your function will run when printing the report rather than the generic odoo function. This is referenced in the documentation 
[HERE](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html#custom-reports)

Take a look at this example.

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, exceptions

class YourReport(models.AbstractModel):
_name = 'report.your_addon.report_template_id'

@api.multi
def render_html(self, data=None):
    report_obj = self.env['report']
    report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('your_addon.report_template_id')
    docs = self.env['your_addon.your_model'].browse(self._ids)

    for doc in docs:
        if not len(doc.object.contract_job_ids) >= 2:
            raise exceptions.ValidationError("You cant run this report\nYou need more contracts!")

    docargs = {
        'doc_model': report.model,
        'docs': docs,
    }
    return report_obj.render('your_addon.report_template_id', docargs)
```